# Unplanned Debian Upgrade

Tags: debian, apt

I would guess this question has been answered before.  If  so, please point me to the link to that topic

I have a computer system purchased from Zareason before they closed their doors.

It originally had Debian Buster installed and continues to update to test/unstable versions using `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade`

All of the entries in sources.list use buster even though the system shows trixie installed:

```
$ cat /etc/issue
Debian GNU/Linux trixie/sid \n \l
```

My questions:

1. I would rather keep it using the stable version until the next release is moved to stable; how can I achieve this
2. Is it possible to downgrade to stable 12.2. or is that too problematic.

My apologies again.  Hopefully I have answered the questions for those have tried to help.

Two files in /etc/apt/sources.list.d.  I am not sure why there are two for the same application. followed with contents below.

```
$ cat wire-desktop.list
deb [arch=amd64] https://wire-app.wire.com/linux/debian stable main



$ cat wire-desktop.list.save
deb [arch=amd64] https://wire-app.wire.com/linux/debian stable main
```

Output for sources.list

```
sources.list:# 
sources.list:# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 10.3.0 _Buster_ - Official amd64 NETINST 20200208-12:07]/ buster main
sources.list:# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 10.3.0 _Buster_ - Official amd64 NETINST 20200208-12:07]/ buster main
sources.list:deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster main
sources.list:deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster main
sources.list:deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main
sources.list:deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main
sources.list:# buster-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
sources.list:deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster-updates main
sources.list:deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster-updates main
sources.list:# This system was installed using small removable media
sources.list:# (e.g. netinst, live or single CD). The matching "deb cdrom"
sources.list:# entries were disabled at the end of the installation process.
sources.list:# For information about how to configure apt package sources,
sources.list:# see the sources.list(5) manual.
sources.list:# deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian sid main contrib non-free
sources.list:# deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian sid main contrib non-free
sources.list:deb [arch=amd64] http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian buster contrib
sources.list:# deb-src [arch=amd64] http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian buster contrib
sources.list:# added following for LibreOffice Writer Thesaures 6/16/2020
sources.list:deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian buster main 
sources.list:# added following to update nVidia driver
sources.list:#deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bullseye main contrib non-free
sources.list:#changed above entry to below 5-1/23
sources.list:#deb https://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm main non-free-firmware
sources.list:#changed above entry to below 9/17/23
sources.list:#deb https://deb.debian.org/debian trixie main non-free-firmware
sources.list.d/wire-desktop.list:deb [arch=amd64] https://wire-app.wire.com/linux/debian stable main
```

Lastly, I am no longer using the non-firmware for NVidea.  As you can be seen, the lines are commented out

Comment: Do you have anything in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`?

Comment: Please add this and its output to your `cd /etc/apt && grep -r . $(find sources.list* -type f -name '*.list' | sort)`

Comment: Please don't provide additional information through comments. [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/758493/edit) the question instead (mind the `{}` code sample block there too).

Comment: David.A I'm sorry but that's totally unreadable in the comments. Please add it to your question (use the [edit] button; enter the text, and then select it and use `{}` to format it as code). You don't need to say "edit" in the text as we can (all) see the full edit history of the question

Comment: Please [don't post pictures of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/100397). Instead, use the [edit] button; enter the text, and then select it and use `{}` to format it as code.

Comment: will do  I will edit the question

Comment: This system seems to be the definition of a [frankendebian](https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian) - personally, I'd backup what I needed, and do a fresh install

Comment: Unfortunately, a fresh install is the best choice.   I still don't know what I did.  Any changes to the repository pointed at buster.  Everything else came from the default apt repository.   I do not get why the system updated to new releases.   It has been 3 years, so it is time to start with a fresh slate.
Thanks for your recommendation